# Java: Regex replacing

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I have this String:

```
foo bar 567 baz
```

Now I want to add before each number the String `num:`.
So the result has to be:

```
foo bar num:567 baz
```

Also this has to work:

```
foo 73761 barbazboom!! 87
result:
foo num:73761 barbazboom!! num:87
```

The regex to search number is this: `[0-9]+`
But I want to replace the matching substring with `num:` + [the matching substring]

I now wrote an example with numbers, but an other example can be: add before each e-mail-address `Email found:`

Comment: Could you please post the code for the  `num:[0-9]+` case?

Comment: What should happen to numbers within words - 123foo, foo123 or foo123foo? Then there's signed numbers (-123), formatted numbers (1,234) and decimals (1,234.567).

Comment: @Greg: Just edit the regex, no?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make use of grouping. You can use the parentheses `(` and `)` to define groups and identify the group in the result by `$n` where `n` is the group index.

```
String string = "foo bar 567 baz";
String replaced = string.replaceAll("(\\d+)", "num:$1");
```

Answer (score 4):

```
"foo bar 567 baz".replaceAll("(\\d+)", "num:$1");
```