# Getting value of $1 from matcher.replaceAll()

Tags: java, regex

In my application I need get the link and break it if it is bigger than 10 (example) characters.
The problem is, if I send the whole text, for example: "this is my website www.stackoverflow.com" directly to this matcher

```
Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("(?i)\\b((?:https?://|www\\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\\s()<>]+|\\(([^\\s()<>]+|(\\([^\\s()<>]+\\)))*\\))+(?:\\(([^\\s()<>]+|(\\([^\\s()<>]+\\)))*\\)|[^\\s`!()\\[\\]{};:\'\".,<>???“”‘’]))");
Matcher matcher = patt.matcher(text);  



matcher.replaceAll("<a href=\"http://$1\" target=\"_blank\">$1</a>");
```

It would show the whole website, without breaking it.

What I was trying to do, is to get the value of $1, so I could break the second one, keeping the first one correctly.

I've got another method to break the string up.

What I want to get is only the website so I could break it after all.

Comment: Nastiest regex I've ever seen.

Comment: I am not sure I can understand what's your goal. Could you post the example input and expected output for it?

Comment: It is almost certainly easier and definitely more readable if you simply output the http part you extract from the string to a variable and then breaking that variable into 10 char pieces through a separate function than to keep adding to that regex and have it done in one line, if it's even possible. In fact, I can't believe you're seriously contemplating how to **add** to that pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use replaceAll; you should iterate through the matches and process each one individually.  Java's Matcher already has an [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29) for this:

```
 // expanding on the example in the 'appendReplacement' JavaDoc:
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("..."); // your URL regexp
 Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
 StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
 while (m.find()) {
     String truncatedURL = m.group(1).replaceFirst("^(.{10}).*","$1..."); // i iz smrt
     m.appendReplacement(sb,
         "<a href=\"http://$1\" target=\"_blank\">"); // simple replacement for $1
     sb.append(truncatedURL);
     sb.append("</a>");
 }
 m.appendTail(sb);
 System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

(For performance, you should factor out compiled Patterns for the replace* calls inside the loop.)

**Edit**: use sb.append() so not to worry about escaping $ and \ in 'truncatedURL'.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have a similar problem to the one mentioned on this question

[Java : replacing text URL with clickable HTML link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909534/java-replacing-text-url-with-clickable-html-link)

they suggested something like this

```java
String basicUrlRegex =  "(.*://[^<>[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]/])"; 
myString.replaceAll(basicUrlRegex, "<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>");
```